# "Warning: json_encode()" in common.inc

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, json

When I access a view, and try to edit/add a field, the overlay shows up but without any content. Afterwards I always get the following warning:

> Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in json_encode() (line 4972 of .../includes/common.inc).

Also, if I try to reload the views options page, and access a field again, an alert window pops up with this content:

> Ein AJAX-Fehler ist aufgetreten. HTTP-Rückgabe-Code 500
>       Im folgenden finden Sie Debugging-Informationen...

[image: screenshot]

I googled without getting any helpful result.
I would be very happy if someone could help me on this one.